# Filter Model Object using Wild-Chars

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I need to be able to filter using wildchars, for example:

```
Surnames.objects.filter(surname="GR%FF%N")
```

should return objects with the following surnames: GRIFFIN, GREFFTEN, GRAFFAIN, and so on. Now obviously `filter` doesn't recognise `%` as a wildchar but the code above should demonstrate what I need to do. I also wish to limit the number of results returned. How would you recommend I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wwork with a regular expression by making use of the [**`__regex`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#regex):

```
Surnames.objects.filter(surname__regex='^GR.*FF.*N$')
```

You can limit the number of results by *slicing* the queryset:

```
Surnames.objects.filter(surname__regex='^GR.*FF.*N$')[:20]
```

here we thus return the first 20 results. Since we did not use `.order_by()` it can return items in any order.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of way to filter on Django that supports your database.

For wildcard query, you do like this:

```
Surnames.objects.filter(surname__icontain="YOUR QUERY TERM")
Surnames.objects.filter(surname__contain="YOUR QUERY TERM")
```

above one are case sensitive and another case-insensitive

Also there are some other lookup that you help you to get your job done:

`startswith` `endswith` `istartswith` `iendswith`

Also, you can query by regex patter with `regex` lookup.

Bellow i showed you how you can your job done:

```
Surnames.objects.filter(surname__regex="YOUR REGEX PATTERN")
Surnames.objects.filter(surname__startswith="YOUR QUERY TERM")
Surnames.objects.filter(surname__iendswith="YOUR QUERY TERM")
Surnames.objects.filter(surname__istartswith="YOUR QUERY TERM")
```